# Set ComboBox SelectedValue to TextBox value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource

I am trying to set the selected item in a Combobox based on the value in a TextBox, using VS2017 C#. The TextBox is populated with data from a BindingSource passed to the Form, and I'm populating the ComboBox with data from a seperate query. This's the Form constructor

```
public Form2(BindingSource dataSource)
{
      string DbConnectionString = @"Data Source=Emp.db;Version=3;";
      SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(DbConnectionString);
      SQLiteDataAdapter DEPDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from DEPARTMENT", dbc);
      DataSet DEPdata = new DataSet();
      DEPDataAdapter.Fill(DEPdata, "DEPARTMENT");

      InitializeComponent();
      formDataSource = dataSource;

      TextBoxfName.DataBindings.Add("Text", formDataSource, "FNAME", true);
      TextBoxlName.DataBindings.Add("Text", formDataSource, "LNAME", true);
      TextBoxDEP.DataBindings.Add("Text", formDataSource, "DEPNO".ToString(), true);
      TextBoxComment.DataBindings.Add("Text", formDataSource, "Comment", true);
        // ComboBoxDep.DataBindings.Add("DEPNO", formDataSource, "DEPNO");
      // ComboBoxDEP.DataBindings.Add("DEPNAME", DEPdata.Tables["DEPARTMENT"], "DEPNO");

      ComboBoxDEP.DataSource = DEPdata.Tables["DEPARTMENT"];
      ComboBoxDEP.DisplayMember = "DEPNAME";
      ComboBoxDEP.ValueMember = "DEPNO";

      ComboBoxDEP.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxDEP.Text);

}
```

I get the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
```

referring to the line  ComboBoxDEP.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxDEP.Text);

The Department table has the DepNo type as an integer. I'm hoping that if I progromatically change the value of the TextBox based on a ComboBox change that'll affect the DataBinding too.  I've also tried many variations on type conversion for the ComboBox ValueMember, I don't understand why this isn't working, it looks straightforward.

Comment: are you trying to select it based on the Id..? the error tells you exactly what the error / problem is.. please update the question and show what column from the query you are trying to bind the dropdown to based on selectedvalue. SelectedValue if the column is a string will be a string.. if the column you are wanting to bind is based on an Index for example Id then the selected value is that columns / field and I don't see `ComboBoxDEP.DataBind()` method either

Comment: You haven't called DataBind() so the textbox text will most likely be empty and consequently the convert will throw an exception.

Comment: I thought that the series of statements starting with ComboBoxDEP.DataSource = DEPdata.Tables["DEPARTMENT"]; did the databinding, rather than setting all of them in one call. The ComboBox is not empty, it displays the DepName as it should, and I have implemented   MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this,  ComboBoxDEP.SelectedValue.ToString(), "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); which shows the selected value of the combobox  ie the column DEPNO from the table whenever I change the ComboBox. But, doing ComboBoxDEP.SelectedValue yields the type conversion error.

Comment: As another test, just hardcoding ComboBoxDEP.SelectedValue = 2; works fine, it displays the correct DataDisplayMemeber

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed this. Instead of using the TextBox value, which always did seem a bit cludgy, I just use the BindingSource

```
ComboBoxDEP.SelectedValue = ((DataRowView)this.formDataSource.Current).Row["DEPNO"];
```

I now have code in the ComboBoxDEP_SelectedValueChanged() method to do something when the ComboBox value changes.